# Function with optional parameter not registering passed value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that has an optional parameter. The problem is that when I pass a parameter, it behaves as if I never passed it.

Here's my code:

```
function sideA(i){

    // i is an optional argument.
    i = i || 'random';

    console.log(i);
}

sideA(0);
```

Here, the console will always display '`random`'. Not sure what's up. Any ideas?

Comment: its correct if you call function without i variable

Comment: Sorry... passed the parameter there... still comes up 'random'

Comment: i don't understand what you want .. can you explain it more please

Comment: Yes the issue is that you are passing 0 which is falsy.

Comment: Right now, the console should say 0, but, with a parameter sent, or not, it always displays random

Comment: if you want to get 0 as parameter passed you can retype i variable to string it will ensure return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0,"",undefined,null` treat as `false`.

in this line

```
i = i || 'random';
```

if i is true then value of i will be assigned else random will be used

try like this

```
 i= typeof i ===  "undefined" ? "random" : i
```

call like this

```
sideA(0) 
sideA() // pass nothing to get random
```

Comment: so how do i pass a 0? I absolutely need to pass a 0

Answer (score 1):

`0` is falsy.

I think you want to check if it's `null` or `undefined`:

```js
function sideA(i) {
  // i is an optional argument.
  i = (i === null || i === undefined ? 'random' : i);

  console.log(i);
}

sideA(0);
```

Alternatively, you can check the `typeof` to see if it is a number:

```js
function sideA(i) {
  // i is an optional argument.
  i = (typeof i === 'number' ? i : 'random');

  console.log(i);
}

sideA(0);
```

---

**Documentation:**

- [Falsy - Glossary | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Comment: so how do i pass a 0? I absolutely need to pass a 0

Answer (score 1):

It is because `0` is a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), so the [Logical](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) [OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_(.7C.7C)) will return the second operand.

If you want to use which ever value is passed, if any even undefined but want to use a default value if no argument is used like `sideA();` then

```
i = arguments.length ? i : 'random';
```

Comment: so how do i pass a 0? I absolutely need to pass a 0

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly testing `i` for being `undefined` , or not. If `i` not `undefined` , return `i` , else return `'random'`

```js
    function sideA(i) {        
      // i is an optional argument.
      // if `i` _not_ `undefined` , `i` = `i` ,
      // else , `i` = `'random'`
      i = i !== undefined ? i : 'random';
    
      console.log(i);
    }

    sideA(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help... Anik beat you to it.